# Unable to compress tiff file in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tiff, cgimage

My app has a requirement to capture a snapshot of a paper document using the iPad camera and pass it to a REST API in Tiff Format.

I have tried to capture an image using "UIImagePickerController" and convert it  to Tiff format using "kUTTypeTIFF" in CGImageDestinationRef. It produces an uncompressed image which is around 20 to 30 MB in ipad pro12.9.

Now I am trying to compress the image using various formats, but I am confused because there are no guides found in swift tiff compression.

*Lang: Swift*

### Code snippet for taking photo,

```
let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! CGImage //2

let imgData = convertToTiffUsingUIImage(imgUI: info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)

//Pass to REST
imageUploadRequest(imgData, uploadUrl: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/user/service.jsp")!, param: ["userName": "xyz"])

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
```

### Convert to tiff image

```
let key = kCGImagePropertyTIFFCompression
let value = 5

var keys = [ unsafeAddressOf(key) ]
var values = [ unsafeAddressOf(value) ]

var keyCallBacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
var valueCallBacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks

let cfDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &keys, &values, 1, &keyCallBacks, &valueCallBacks) 

let data = NSMutableData()

let dr: CGImageDestinationRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, kUTTypeTIFF, 1, cfDictionary)!

CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, imgUI.CGImage!, nil);

CGImageDestinationFinalize(dr);

print(data.length);

if data.length > 0 {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data:data)!, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

But this doesn't result in a compressed Image.

Can anyone help me to understand the Tiff file compression in swift ?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot compress the tiff image itself (tiff is uncompressed, it's weird for an API to require such a format), what you can do is zip (or targz) the file and upload that file,  it the API would probably not accept it.

Comment: @HAS Compressed tiff is a thing, but Cocoa does not support it AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks @matt, I didn't know that, so I stay corrected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be passing photos around as TIFF. A photo wants to be a JPG, and that is the format you should be using. To put it another way, the compressed version of a photo *is* a JPG. Don't use TIFF as an intermediary.

(A small number of recent devices support RAW, but you can't count on that.)

Answer (score 1):

This is my crude attempt to convert the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/792978/4186278) answer.

```
import Cocoa
import ImageIO
import CoreServices

func writeCCITTTiffWithCGImageURL(im: CGImage, url: CFURL)
{
   guard let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.genericGrayGamma2_2) else { print("Color space deosn't exist"); return }
   guard let bitmapCtx = CGContext(data: nil, width: im.width, height: im.height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue) else { print("Could not make bitmapContext"); return }

   bitmapCtx.draw(im, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: im.width, height: im.height))
   guard let grayScaleImage: CGImage = bitmapCtx.makeImage()
   else { print("Could not make grayScale Image"); return }

   let tiffOptions: Dictionary<String, Int> = [String(kCGImagePropertyTIFFCompression) : 4]
   let options: NSDictionary = [String(kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary) : tiffOptions, kCGImagePropertyDepth : 1]

   guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeTIFF, 1, nil) else { print("Could not make imageDestination"); return }
   CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, grayScaleImage, options)
   CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is example:

```
   import UIKit
    
    import ImageIO
    
    import MobileCoreServices
    
    
    static func converterImgtoTIFF(img: UIImage) -> String{
            
            let options: NSDictionary =     [:]
            let convertToTIFF = img.toData(options: options, type: .tiff)
            guard let bmpData = convertToTIFF else {
                print(" ERROR: could not convert image to a bitmap bmpData var.")
                return ""
            }
            print("---------- convertToTIFF ----------------")
            let imagTiff = convertToTIFF?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters) ?? ""
           
            print("convert To TIFF =>>", imagTiff.count)
            
            return imagTiff
        }


extension UIImage {
    func toData (options: NSDictionary, type: ImageType) -> Data? {
        guard cgImage != nil else { return nil }
        return toData(options: options, type: type.value)
    }

    func toData (options: NSDictionary, type: CFString) -> Data? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        return autoreleasepool { () -> Data? in
            let data = NSMutableData()
            guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data as CFMutableData, type, 1, nil) else { return nil }
            CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, cgImage, options)
            CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)
            return data as Data
        }
    }

    enum ImageType {
        case tiff // TIFF image
        var value: CFString {
            switch self {
            case .tiff: return kUTTypeTIFF
            }
        }
    }
}
```